# How can I put an octagon inside of this octagon html

Tags: html, css, web, shapes

I'm not an expert with html so this is why I'm asking this question, so I could create an hexagon, but I need to create another one inside of the hexagon created, so this is why I'm asking if any of you guys could help me, thanks in advance!

```css
.octagonWrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
}

.octagon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.octagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
     * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
     * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
     */
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: '';
  border: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='octagonWrap'>
  <div class='octagon'></div>
  <div class="octagontwo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how big you want the hexagon to be but this should give you a good starting point.

HTML

```
<div class='octagonWrap'>
  <div class='octagon'></div>
</div>
<div class='octagonWrapTwo'>
  <div class='octagontwo'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.octagonWrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
}

.octagonWrapTwo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 45%;
  left: 24%;
}

.octagon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.octagontwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.octagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
     * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
     * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
     */
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: '';
  border: inherit;
}

.octagontwo:before {
  position: absolute;
  /* There needs to be a negative value here to cancel
     * out the width of the border. It's currently -3px,
     * but if the border were 5px, then it'd be -5px.
     */
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: '';
  border: inherit;
}
```